# Get a list of distinct items and their count

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have an object, that has many properties but the only two to worry about are:

`myobject.ID` which is an `int`
`myobject.Names` which is a `HashSet`

Then I have a `List` of those objects that looks something similar to this:

```
List<myobject>
```

I use Linq to get a some of the data into a repeater, but I'm not sure how to get the list of Names and how often they show up.

Want to use Linq to avoid having to loop through the data.

As my tags should show, this is an ASP.NET solution using C#.

**Some clarification:**
Lets say I have just three items in my list:
Item 1 has John, Fred, Jack in its names.
Item 2 has John, Fred, Joe in its names.
Item 3 has John in its names.

I am trying to return the following:
John - 3
Fred - 2
Jack - 1
Joe - 1

Also, as a note I am familiar with having to write my own comparer for my object, I'm just missing the 'how to' for the overall solution in my thoughts.

Comment: Hi, when you say "how to get the list of Names and how often they show up." : do you mean you want to count the number of instances of 'myobject in List<myobject> where the '.Names property contains a pointer to a valid list (HashSet); in other words, the '.Names property's value is not null ? Or are you wanting to build a new collection of 'myObject containing only those with a vaid HashSet in the '.Names property ? A little clarification, please.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is how I understand the problem that you are trying to solve. You have a list of `myobject`s. Each `myobject` has a property called `Names` which is a `HashSet` of `string`s (i.e., `HashSet<string>`). You want to count the number of times each `string` that appears in some `myobject.Names` appears in all the `myobject.Names`. That is, you have

```
"Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"
"Alice", "Bob", "Donald"
"Alice", "Donald", "Ernie"
```

as three `myobject.Names` and you want to see

```
"Alice", 3
"Bob", 2
"Charlie", 1
"Donald", 2
"Ernie", 1
```

If so:

```
var query = list.SelectMany(x => x.Names)
                .GroupBy(s => s)
                .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

foreach(var result in query) {
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Count: {1}", result.Name, result.Count);
}
```

I do not see what role `myobject.ID` plays here. Please qualify.

Comment: myobject.ID doesn't really play a role, I just wanted to make it clear that it wasn't a simple HashSet object.

Comment: Okay. Then I believe that the above addresses your question. Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: Your example has GroupBy(s), but s doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, should be `GroupBy(s => s)`.

Comment: Never mind... typo in my code.  Still working out your solution to see if it works.

Comment: This has saved me a lot of work. Thank you very much @jason.

Answer (score 7):

```
var query = yourList
            .SelectMany(x => x.Names)
            .GroupBy(x => x, (y, z) => new { Name = y, Count = z.Count() });

// and to test...
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.Name, item.Count);
}
```